# Error 193 when running build_js file of opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I was trying to generate opencv.js file i install all the required dependency but when i execute the `build_js.py` file i get an error.

[image: screenshot of error]

I read that the error 193 occurs because of 64bit system trying to load a 32bit. 
But all of the dependency are of 64bit which were installed by emsdk.I am using opencv 3.4.1

Comment: Please put the error message in as text and not an image.

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50748854/1691132