# OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application opencv.js

Tags: javascript, python, opencv, subprocess, command-prompt

I have tried to build `opencv.js` from [the tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d4/da1/tutorial_js_setup.html) on their page.

I have done all the steps except the last one to build it:

```
C:\Users\student>python C:\Users\student\opencv\platforms\js\build_js.py documents
```

which gives me this error:

```
Args: Namespace(build_dir='documents', build_doc=False, build_test=False, build_wasm=False, clean_build_dir=False, config_only=False, emscripten_dir=None, enable_exception=False, opencv_dir='C:\\Users\\student\\opencv', skip_config=False)
Cannot get Emscripten path, please specify it either by EMSCRIPTEN environment variable or --emscripten_dir option.
```

I try using this then

```
C:\Users\student>python C:\Users\student\opencv\platforms\js\build_js.py --emscripten=C:\Users\student\emsdk\emscripten\1.37.36 documents
```

with the `--emscripten` option but I got this instead:

```
Args: Namespace(build_dir='documents', build_doc=False, build_test=False, build_wasm=False, clean_build_dir=False, config_only=False, emscripten_dir='C:\\Users\\student\\emsdk\\emscripten\\1.37.36', enable_exception=False, opencv_dir='C:\\Users\\student\\opencv', skip_config=False)
Check dir C:\Users\student\documents (create: True, clean: False)
Check dir C:\Users\student\opencv (create: False, clean: False)
Check dir C:\Users\student\emsdk\emscripten\1.37.36 (create: False, clean: False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\student\opencv\platforms\js\build_js.py", line 215, in <module>
    builder = Builder(args)
  File "C:\Users\student\opencv\platforms\js\build_js.py", line 84, in __init__
    self.emcc_version = determine_emcc_version(self.emscripten_dir)
  File "C:\Users\student\opencv\platforms\js\build_js.py", line 62, in determine_emcc_version
    ret = subprocess.check_output([os.path.join(emscripten_dir, "emcc"), "--version"])
  File "C:\Users\student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Users\student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 403, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\student\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I have searched for this problem for almost 2 days but nothing solve it.

I'm using Windows 10 64bit.

Comment: The error message suggested to use the `--emscripten_dir` option but you used `--emscripten` instead. What happens if you use the former option?

Comment: i have tried with the --emscripten_dir it gave me the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `opencv\platforms\js\build_js.py` file, and replace this line:

```
ret = subprocess.check_output([os.path.join(emscripten_dir, "emcc"), "--version"])
```

with this:

```
ret = subprocess.check_output([os.path.join(emscripten_dir, "emcc.bat"), "--version"])
```

Hope this will be fixed in next opencv version.